# XCode - Failed to create provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I am enrolled as an Apple Developer. I'v created my first app (yay!) but when I try to archive the upload button is greyed out. [Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k77hK.png) It says the my distribution requires enrolment and I realised I was using my personal team. I changed it back to my developer team and got [this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcJQD.png) I've tried many different methods to solve this. Including deleting my certificates and re-downloading. My certificates are distribution certificates. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the provisioning profile. You need to create it in dev portal.

The best tutorial to make everything work is [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/distributing-ios-apps-with-itunes-connect--cms-21672)

Follow every step and you'll achieve what is needed.

Comment: I tried what it says on the website but when I try to create an app ID it says that the string is not available. I assumed this was because of the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do anything wrong. Just run your project and then it should work or click try agin. You could also try signing in agin in preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not exactly sure what I did but something did the trick. Here are the steps on XCode:

1. Turn off automatically signing in the General tab.
2. Change the bundle identifier (I just added a '2' on the end).

   i. To change bundle id, go to build settings search up 'packaging'.

   ii. In the 'packaging' section change the Product Bundle Identifier key to your chosen bundle identifier.

   iii. Press cmd + shift + k or go to Product -> Clean.
3. On the apple developer website, download the provisioning profile onto your computer.
4. In the build settings I changed all the Code Signing Identities to 'iOS Distribution'.
5. In the General tab change the Signing (Debug) provisioning profile to the one you downloaded. Do the same for Signing (Release).

Done!

Thank you **Tung Fam** for telling me to chang the Bundle ID.